# Loading JSP page in a <div> using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
These are the two divs in my page

      #apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:115px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:4;
}
        #apDiv2 {
        position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:5;
}

where apDiv2 is nested in apDiv1 
<div id="apDiv1">
<div id="apDiv2" style="overflow:auto"></div>
</div>

what i wanna do is to load another page 'server_gen.jsp' in apDiv2 by using 

    $('#apDiv2').load('server_gen.jsp');
```

- The page is being loaded in apDiv2 as expected ... but the problem is
  that the  'server_gen.jsp' page elements are not being shown on the
  top in apDiv2 ...(I want the   server_gen.jsp page elements to be
  shown from 0px of apDiv2) ... how can i show the server_gen.jsp
  elements from the to(i.e starting from 0px) of apDiv2? Please help

Comment: Maybe, there is element in "server_gen.jsp", with margin-padding, or something. Please share us the html of 'server_gen.jsp'.

Comment: The problem got solved by adding top:0px; in style of one of the div (that contained data/elements) in "server_gen.jsp" ..anyways ...thanks for replying Guys

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;` in `#apDiv2` style

Comment: i'm getting the same problem after adding vertical-align: top; in apDiv2